# How can I change HyperLinkedModelSerializer's default <pk> lookup_url_kwarg?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to use `HyperLinkedModelSerializer` in order to add a `url` field for my `Book` model. Here is the solution you'd typically find in the average tutorial:

```
# serializers.py
class BookSerializer(HyperLinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("title", "url",)

# views.py
class BookView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("<pk>/", BookDetailView.as_view(), name="book-detail"),
]
```

And that works all right. But now I need to change the URL conf in order to match the book id, not with `<pk>`, but with `<fiction_id>`. So I figured I'd just change it!

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("<fiction_id>/", BookDetailView.as_view(), name="book-detail"),
]
```

Now comes the crash:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "fiction-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

I've tried fiddling with the `lookup_field`, `lookup_url_kwargs` in my view:

```
# views.py
class BookView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"
    lookup_url_kwargs = "fiction_id"
```

I've tried reminding the serializer to actually look for the (default) "pk":

```
# serializers.py
class BookSerializer(HyperLinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("title", "url",)
        extra_kwargs = {
            "url": {"lookup_field": "pk"},
        }
```

I've tried combinations of these, to no avail. It looks like you can't use anything but `<pk>` if you want to take advantage of `HyperLinkedModelSerializer`'s url field. The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined) doesn't seem to offer a way to change that behaviour:

> By default hyperlinks are expected to correspond to a view name that matches the style '{model_name}-detail', and **looks up the instance by a pk keyword argument**.

How can I change this behaviour, or is it bound to become too messy?

Answer (score 1):

You should check `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` implementation and see that it uses a `serializer_related_field` defaulting to `HyperlinkedRelatedField`

```
class HyperlinkedModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A type of `ModelSerializer` that uses hyperlinked relationships instead
    of primary key relationships. Specifically:

    * A 'url' field is included instead of the 'id' field.
    * Relationships to other instances are hyperlinks, instead of primary keys.
    """
    serializer_related_field = HyperlinkedRelatedField
    ...
```

And then `HyperlinkedRelatedField` has a class attribute `lookup_field` defaulting to `pk`

```
class HyperlinkedRelatedField(RelatedField):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    ...
```

What you can do is to use a custom `HyperlinkedRelatedField` with your own `lookup_field`

```
from rest_framework.relations import HyperlinkedRelatedField
from rest_framework.serializers import HyperlinkedModelSerializer


class BookHyperlinkedRelatedField(HyperlinkedRelatedField):
    lookup_field = 'fiction_id'


class BookSerializer(HyperLinkedModelSerializer):
    serializer_related_field = BookHyperlinkedRelatedField
    
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("title", "url",)
```

Comment: Thank you, however I wasn't looking to change the lookup in the queryset (`lookup_field`) but in the URL match pattern (`lookup_url_kwarg`). It turns out you CAN achieve this by just adding `{"lookup_url_kwarg": "fiction_id"}` in the url field's extra_kwargs AND `looking_url_kwarg = "fiction_id"` in the `BookView` class. My mistake while investigating the problem was I typed `lookup_url_kwargs` in plural and consequently got another Key Error, which lead me to think the pattern lookup couldn't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to give the url field's new name for the lookup in the matched pattern by passing it through the `extra_kwargs` dictionary:

```
# serializers.py
class BookSerializer(HyperLinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("title", "url",)
        extra_kwargs = {
            "url": {"lookup_url_kwarg": "fiction_id"},
        }
```

Also remember to modify the corresponding view:

```
# views.py
class BookView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = "fiction_id"
```

Do not write `lookup_url_kwargs` in plural.
You don't need to meddle with the `lookup_field` at any level as long as the lookup will be done on the model's primary key.